# Might a "normal matter" body orbit a dark matter body?

Tags: dark-matter

Are there any main stream theories of dark matter that would allow for it to form bodies which could participate in orbits with normal matter?

So, say, could a normal matter planet be captured and orbit around a "dark star"?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, given that dark matter interacts gravitationally.

Comment: I am worried that dark matter may not be capable of forming dense bodies

Comment: Dark matter might not form dense bodies, but one can orbit a fuzzy halo of dark matter too.

Comment: I think "baryonic matter" is "normal matter". Unless dark matter is MACHOs, in which case it is a dense body of normal matter.

Comment: right, clearly a planet might orbit some time of MACHO ...

Comment: "Dark" is the astronomer's term for something for which evidence exists, but which has not directly been observed.  "Dark matter" is something massive that is _presumed_ to be distributed throughout galaxies because the visible mass does not account for the way in which galaxies seem to evolve. Nobody knows what the dark matter consists of. Since nobody knows what it consists of, nobody can really say whether or not it could form dense, compact "bodies."

Comment: Flying dark matter can't be stopped, so it doesn't form dense bodies. However, if enough dark matter would get in a small enough volume, it could form a black hole. This makes a difference, because a black hole is the only thing that can stop flying dark matter and "eat" it. The caveat though is that dark matter makes the same black holes as ordinary matter. For example, Sagittarius A*, a supermassive black hole in the center of our galaxy, could potentially be made of dark matter and we would never know. Although dark matter has not been observed and options for its existence are running out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense, all stars, planets etc. in every galaxy are "captured" by dark matter because galaxies would not exist in their current form without dark matter to hold them together. However, there are good observational reasons to think that dark matter does not aggregate into anything more compact than a galaxy-sized halo - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Dark_matter_aggregation_and_dense_dark_matter_objects.